# Is there a way to parse inline literals?

Tags: python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

My project uses a substitution quite a bit (`.. |apipath| replace:: http://domain/api/v1`), and I'd like to be able to use this substitution inside an inline literal block. I want something like the following rST source:

```
Request URL: ``|apipath|/endpoint/method/param``
```

to turn into the following html output:

```
Request URL: <code>http://domain/api/v1/endpoint/method/param</code>
```

Instead, it outputs as

```
Request URL: <code>|apipath|/endpoint/method/param</code>
```

Any way you know of to get this to work?

I've tried playing with custom roles and classes. I know that the `parsed-literal` directive is available, but that appears to only create block content, not inline.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how if at all possible, but perhaps this at least visually comes close to it.

```
Request URL: |apipath|\ ``/endpoint/method/param``

.. |apipath| replace:: ``http://domain/api/v1``
```

or `` :literal:`http://domain/api/v1` `` in the replace contents.